# Apache mod_rewrite redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I just created a subdomain info.domain.com and what I want is to relate each user who logs on my website with a subdomain which is for example jose.domain.com, juan.domain.com etc ...
What would be the code for the. htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use wildcard subdomains. The following should pass everything other than www to your index.php file with the GET param user equal to the users name.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.com [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /index.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: this give me Internal Server Error